# Randomized Quick Sort worst case Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Time complexity of Normal Quick Sort in worst case is O(n^2) when one of the following 2 cases occur:

1. Input is already sorted either in increasing or decreasing order
2. All elements in input array are same

In above two mentioned cases, PARTITION algorithms will divide array into two sub-parts, one with (n-1) elements and second with 0 elements

To avoid this bad case, we use another version of QuickSort i.e **Randomized Quick-Sort**, in which an random element is selected as pivot. The expected T.C of randomized quick-sort is **theta(nlogn)**.

My question is, for what input/case, randmized Quick-Sort will result into worst time complexity of O(n^2)?

Comment: lf the randomised pivot selector happens to select e.g. the smallest element N times in a row, you will get the worst possible performance. The probability of this particular case is about 1/n! Of course there are more cases to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input contains elements that are all the same, the runtime of randomized quick-sort is O(n^2). That's assuming you're using the same PARTITION algorithm as in the deterministic version. The analysis is identical.

Here's an implementation of randomized quicksort which counts the number of compares performed:

```
import random

def quicksort(A, lo, hi):
    if lo >= hi:
        return 0
    p, compares = partition(A, lo, hi)
    compares += quicksort(A, lo, p - 1)
    compares += quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
    return compares

def partition(A, lo, hi):
    r = random.randrange(lo, hi+1)
    A[r], A[hi] = A[hi], A[r]
    pivot = A[hi]
    i = lo - 1
    compares = 0
    for j in xrange(lo, hi):
        compares += 1
        if A[j] < pivot:
            i = i + 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
    compares += 1
    if A[hi] < A[i + 1]:
        A[i + 1], A[hi] = A[hi], A[i + 1]
    return i + 1, compares


for x in xrange(10, 510, 40):
    compares = quicksort([1] * x, 0, x-1)
    print x, compares
```

The output clearly shows O(n^2) runtime:

```
10 54
50 1274
90 4094
130 8514
170 14534
210 22154
250 31374
290 42194
330 54614
370 68634
410 84254
450 101474
490 120294
```

Comment: Even if all elements are same the depth of randomized partition tree is still `O(lg n)`. So randomized quicksort won't fall into `O(n ^ 2)` even when all inputs are same.

Comment: @taskinoor There will be one partition of size n-1 and one partition of size 1. The randomization doesn't help, since the pivot value will always be the same (since all elements are identical).

Comment: If you partition into three parts (x_i<pivot, x_i==pivot, x_i>pivot) as you probably should, then the run time in this case is O(n).

Comment: @n.m. yes, but it's clear from the question that their PARTITION function doesn't do this.

Comment: @PaulHankin 
"lf the randomised pivot selector happens to select e.g. the smallest element N times in a row, you will get the worst possible performance. The probability of this particular case is about 1/n! "
Can this possibility also lead to worst case T.C of Randomized Quick-Sort?

Comment: @GamRaj it depends what you mean by "worst case time complexity" of a random algorithm. It could mean "worst case expected time complexity" or it could mean "the maximum time complexity across all possible universes of random choices". With the former definition, it doesn't make sense to consider one particular set of random choices, but with the latter definition it does make sense. Basically as always, you have to be clear what definitions you're using.

Comment: I meant "the maximum time complexity across all possible universes of random choices".  
Sure, I will take care of it next time.